# TypeError: this.state.annonces.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi I have an API and from React which represents my frontend I recover the data from the API to display it but from there I encounter this problem.

Thank you in advance for guiding me, explain to me clearly what the problem is

```
    constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {

    api: api.api,
    annonces: []
  }

}

componentDidMount = () => {
  console.log(this.state.annonces_id)
  this.onLoaodPreloader();
  this.getAnnonce();
}
getAnnonce = () => {
  var baseApiUrl = this.state.api
  axios.get(baseApiUrl + 'annonces' ,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}`
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      this.setState({
        annonces: response.data,
      })

    }).catch((erreur) => {
      console.log(erreur)
    })
}
render() {
        console.log(this);
            const { annonces } = this.state
        const renderAnnonces = annonces.map((annonces, index) =>{
              return (
                  <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-3" key={index}>
                    {annonces.meeting_type}
                    </div>
              )

        });

  return <div className="component-annonces">{renderAnnonces}</div>;
}
```

Comment: upload some code

Comment: It seems you are new to StackOverflow. Please add your code snippet and try to indicate the area you are having issues

Comment: In simple terms annonces in not a array

Comment: @Sagar I declared it as an array

Comment: @FridayAmeh    this is my first time asking questions here i'm sorry

Comment: @CyrusZei I added the code

Comment: Good that you have added your code. so what is the problem?

Comment: You omitted the problem statement. Try and edit your code by adding the problem statement

Comment: @FridayAmeh i get this error TypeError: this.state.annonces.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure your `response.data` is not an array. since `.map` only works if it is an array.

if you `console.log('response data type :', typeof response.data)` you will see what type the data is.

your data needs to be in an array for the `.map` to work

Comment: response data type : object
annonces.js:72 annonces {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, componentDidMount: ƒ, …}
annonces.js:72 annonces {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, componentDidMount: ƒ, …}

Comment: here is your problem, it says that the data is of the type object and it needs to be in a Array

Comment: ok thanks i will see how to solve the problem i thought the data was linked to the announcement declared in state which is an array i am new on react

Comment: no problem, could you maybe update your question with a sample of the response.data, take like the first three items on the whole response and then I can update the answer on how to put that into an Array